# new command line tool: unique name

Tags: linux, shell, command-line, rpm, dpkg

I want to write a new command line tool.

The name should be short, and it should not clash with an existing name.

How can know that an other command line tool does not have this name?

Just checking my system is not a solution. The name should be unique for:

- ubuntu
- debian
- red hat
- suse

Comment: Pick a name, google "linux your-tool-name", if it doesn't return something then huzzah!

Comment: should be short, how short? what does your tool do? `mmm mm xyx myx xmx ...` are they ok?

Comment: use package search to search for packages containing files with the name of your choice: http://packages.ubuntu.com/ - http://www.debian.org/distrib/packages#search_packages - http://rpm.pbone.net/ ...

Comment: Single letters are not often use, and you can't get shorter than that. On the top row of the keyboard these seem to be unused (no package on Ubuntu claims that they include a program of the name): `q`, `e`, `t`, `y`, `u`, `o`, `p`

Answer (score 2):

Don't bother.  pick any name you want that doesn't collide with something in your current PATH and that no one in your current group recognizes.  If the tool becomes popular, you will have a name collision very quickly and can change the name at that time.  If your tool is popular enough, you will keep the name.  (This happened to `git`, for example, and the unpopular package previously known as `git` is still unpopular, while the version control system kept the name.)

Perhaps "don't bother" is a bit strong.  Perform some search, exert some effort, but not more than a few hours at most.  If you can't find a name collision after a few hours of effort, then the other tool that is using the name is not sufficiently well known to worry about any potential problems.